# Do I need to clear APC cache after new post?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, apc, varnish

I'm running a Wordpress/WooCommerce. I recently switched over to APC + Varnish over W3TC + Memcached. I'm using the APC Backend dropin plugin for Wordpress.

I know that Varnish cache needs to be cleared whenever a post or comment is updated/created. I'm using a plugin that does the clearing for me. My question is, does APC cache also need to be cleared every time a new comment is made, a post is edited, or a new post is created? If so, how can I do it? I know there is a PHP function to clear ALL cache,  but is it possible to only clear the cache of a specific page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, APC cache has to be cleared only after PHP files modification.
Ad you shouldn't clear full cache, use apc_compile_file() only for files that you uploaded/modified (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-compile-file.php)

Comment: Does this apply for the new ZendOptimizer Plus, too? I've been thinking of moving to it but W3TC doesn't support it. However, if I don't need to clear cache after new posts, then W3TC doesn't need to support it.

Comment: With all opcode caching teqniques idea is the same : when you change the PHP source file then cache has to be invalidated. If you change something in Database/Memcache etc you don't have to invalidate opcode cache. 

Opcacode caching is low level thing, W3TC can use it, but primarly WT3C is used to cache objectss in memory, cache DB responses etc. By itself it cannot cache opcode (you need a proper module to do it).
I'm not very familiar with W3TC, but I thing that it was using APC as a in-memory storage, so you can use ZendOpcache and ACPU (APC without opcode cache, just in-memory storage)

Comment: Thank you! I may try making the switch.